# hibernate spatial error: type "geometry" does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, geometry, hibernate-mapping, postgis

I want to use hibernate spatial to handle my spatial objects.I am using `hibernate-spatial-4.0.1` with `hibernate 4.2`. My dialect:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect</property>
```

I have an Entity like this:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(CK.LAYER_PICTURES)
public class PicsLayerItem extends LayerItem {

   @Column(name = "place_name")
   private String placeName;

   public void setPlaceName(String name) {
       this.placeName = name;
   }

   public String getPlaceName() {
       return this.placeName;
   }


   @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
   @Column(name = "locations", nullable = true)
   private LineString locations;

   public LineString getLocations() {
       return locations;
   }
}
```

The problem that when hibernate updates schema, it faced this error:

```
ERROR [http-nio-8084-exec-53] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table public.tree_item add column locations GEOMETRY
ERROR [http-nio-8084-exec-53] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist
```

I guess my postgresql does not support the geomtry types. I use PgAdminIII. It is postgis. It supports data types like `polygon`.

[image]

What can I do solving this problem?
Similar question with no answer:  [Type geometry not found with postgis and hibernate-spatial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518130/type-geometry-not-found-with-postgis-and-hibernate-spatial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Postgresql does not support geometry. You need to add `postgis` extension to it in order to create spatial databases. So download suitable postgis extension for your postgresql from [here](http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/). Then install it in the postgresql installation folder exactly, for example (in my system) in the following path:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenGeo\OpenGeo Suite\pgsql\9.1
```